# Usage of XSS Injection Tool : XSSer

Tags: svn, xss

I checked out a copy of XSSer from :

```
svn co https://xsser.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xsser xsser
```

to my Mac OS X 10.7 and try to run its example :

```
python XSSer.py -u 'http://testasp.vulnweb.com' -g 'Search.asp?tfSearch=' -proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:8118? -referer '666.666.666.666? -user-agent 'correct audit' -Fuzz -s
```

but in the console it said, `XSSer.py: No such file or directory`

Same case when I download a `tar.gz` version. Did I miss something?